# Why is xlCellTypeConstants, 22 faster than a loop when deleting?

Tags: excel, vba

I found a snippet of VBA for deleting rows in which the column value contains **text**.

It seems to work much faster than a loop statement. I looked online to figure out  how Specifically `xlCellTypeConstants, 22` works.

```
[D:D].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 22).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're providing the first argument as `xlCellTypeConstants`, so that means the second parameter can be a bitwise combination of:

```
xlNumbers = 1
xlTextValues = 2
xlLogical = 4
xlErrors = 16
```

In your case, you're using a hard-coded number of 22, which is the bitwise equivalent of `xlErrors Or xlLogical Or xlTextValues`

See this [article](http://excelmatters.com/2015/06/02/super-secret-specialcells/) ([Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805131258/http://excelmatters.com/2015/06/02/super-secret-specialcells/)) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much! Extremely appreciated.

Comment: @user8213417 Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it has answered your question. ;-)

Comment: The original link has died.